# RabbitMQ connectionFactory - wrong scheme in amqp URI:

Tags: spring-cloud

we provisioned a rabbitMQ service with Cloud Foundry and its looks like this:
 "amqp+ssl": {
       "host": xxx,
       "password": xxxx
       "port": 5671,
       "ssl": true,
       "uri": "amqps:/......

When i push my app i get an error: wrong scheme in amqp URI...

Does someone know how to change the scheme, cause i need amqps?

For now I've got this:

```
@Configuration
@ServiceScan
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationInstanceInfo applicationInfo() {
        return cloud().getApplicationInstanceInfo();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(){
        // I would say here I have to configure the amqp connectionFactory??
        // But how? :(
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
```

It would be nice if someone has a small code snippet how to do it right with spring cloud. I've noticed the existence of spring-cloud-connectors, but there is no example how to use it ... only how to use and create a custom service connector!?

Thank you for your help and time.

Vladimir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by lower versions of `spring-cloud-core`. Any version before 1.1.1.RELEASE does not recognize the [`amqps`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/service/common/AmqpServiceInfo.java#L19) scheme.

And, since this artifact is usually dependency of [spring-cloud-connectors](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors), the versions for these should be also equal to or greater than 1.1.1.RELEASE. If spring-boot pom parent is configured you also need to take care of the version of any artifacts that has `spring-boot-dependencies`. It needs to be equal to or greater than 1.1.1.RELEASE since there is a `dependencyManagement` section which can override dependencies explicitly set.